# Load a PHP class multiple times

Tags: php, function, class

I've created a class which has multiple private an public functions and an construct function. It's an client to connect to the vCloud API. I want two objects loaded with different initiations of this class. They have to exist in parallel.

```
$vcloud1 = new vCloud(0, 'system');
$vcloud2 = new vCloud(211, 'org');
```

When I check the output of `$vcloud1` it's loaded with info of `$vcloud2`. Is this correct, should this happen? Any idea how I can load a class multiple times and isolate both class loads?

This is part of my class, it holds the most important functions. Construct with user and org to login to. If info in the DB exists, then we authenticate with DB info, else we authenticate with system level credentials. So I would like to have two class loads, one with the user level login and one with system level login.

```
class vCloud {
    private $client;
    private $session_id;
    private $sdk_ver = '7.0'; 
    private $system_user = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    private $system_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    private $system_host = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    private $org_user;
    private $org_password;
    private $org_host;
    private $base_url;

    public function __construct($customerId, $orgName) {

        if ($this->vcloud_get_db_info($customerId)) {
            $this->base_url = 'https://' . $this->org_host . '/api/';
            $this->base_user = $this->org_user . "@" . $orgName;
            $this->base_password = $this->org_password;
        } else {
            $this->base_url = 'https://' . $this->system_host . '/api/';
            $this->base_user = $this->system_user;
            $this->base_password = $this->system_password;
        }

        $response = \Httpful\Request::post($this->base_url . 'sessions')
            ->addHeaders([
                'Accept' => 'application/*+xml;version=' . $this->sdk_ver
            ])
            ->authenticateWith($this->base_user, $this->base_password)
            ->send();

        $this->client = Httpful\Request::init()
            ->addHeaders([
                'Accept' => 'application/*+xml;version=' . $this->sdk_ver,
                'x-vcloud-authorization' => $response->headers['x-vcloud-authorization']
            ]);

        Httpful\Request::ini($this->client);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $deleted = $this->vcloud_delete_session();
        if (!$deleted) {
            echo "vCloud API session could not be deleted. Contact administrator if you see this message.";
        }
    }

    private function vcloud_delete_session() {
        if (isset($this->client)) {
            $response = $this->client::delete($this->base_url . 'session')->send();

            return $response->code == 204;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function vcloud_get_db_info($customerId) {
        global $db_handle;

        $result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * from vdc WHERE customer=" . $customerId);

        if ($result) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if ($row['org_host'] != "") {
                    $this->org_user = $row['org_user'];
                    $this->org_password = $row['org_password'];
                    $this->org_host = $row['org_host'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function vcloud_get_admin_orgs() {
        $response = $this->client::get($this->base_url . 'query?type=organization&sortAsc=name&pageSize=100')->send();

        return $response->body;
    }
}
```

Comment: You tell us.... we have no idea what the definition of class `vCloud` is

Comment: Can you post the content of vcloud? Your instantiation seems correct

Comment: please provide some code snippet of your class can help us to understand what exactly the issue is.

Comment: `"SELECT * from vdc WHERE customer=" . $customerId`.... Your customerIds are string values (`'user1'` and `'user2'`), so the SQL you're executing isn't valid.... and please learn to use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: The first argument is an integer, I have edited my example. SQL query is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vcloud1 = new vCloud('user1', 'system');
$vcloud2 = new vCloud('user2', 'org');
```

This is enough to make two instances which are not related.

I suppose your database is returning the same results.

Comment: No that's not it. I drilled it down to httpful client I use to grab the XML info. When I dump it's info after each $vcloudX i get the same results while in my class I set variables different. I think I need to reset httpful at __destruct, correct?

Comment: This could be it. I haven't used Httpful

Comment: Output of both $vcloud's starts with `object(vCloud)#2 (10) { ["client":"vCloud":private]=> object(Httpful\Request)#12 (22)` . This shows the client is shared amongst both $vcloud's. I need to find a way to isolate both clients. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I have posted the same question to the developers github site: [link](https://github.com/nategood/httpful/issues/265)

Answer (score 0):

How about providing a custom `equals` method to each object that retreives an instance of vCloud?

```
class vCloud {
  //Other definitions

  public function equals(vCloud $other){
    //Return true if $other is same as this class (has same client_id etc etc)
  }
}
```

So you just need to do as the code says:

```
$vcloud1 = new vCloud('user1', 'system');
$vcloud2 = new vCloud('user2', 'org');

if($vcloud1.equals($vclous2)){
 echo "Entries are the same";
} else {
 echo "Entries are NOT the same";
}
```

Also you may need to have various getter and setter methods into your class definitions. What is needed for you to do is to fill the `equals` method.